# Centering absolute div; works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS:

http://pastebin.com/LwMNdxnL

My `<body>` contains:

```
<div class="image-wrap"><img class="image invisible" id="0" src="..."></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is center an image contained in a `position: absolute` div, whilst scaling it down if above browser width.

This works perfectly in Firefox, but Chromium seems not to allow divs to extend beyond the screen, so it always has max. half the window width.

Comment: Is chrome adding its own class to the div? Do you have a live link I can see?

Comment: Could you write this up on http://jsfiddle.net so we could see what happens please. (It can be used to test HTML and CSS, as well as javascript)

Comment: http://einlander.com/zerodc/Test_Folder/ This is an example of it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
body{
    background: #000000;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: Consolas, monospace
```

}

good luck

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't work though, sadly. I'll try to get some example folder up.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it now:

```
.image{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9}

.visible{
visibility: visible}

.invisible{
visibility: hidden;
width: 0px}
```

With this and no wrapping div, it seems to work in both browsers; well, still doesn't solve the issue with chrome positioning.